# Multiplication of different FLAGs - fixed effects model

Tags: r

I want to perform a regression in a fixed-effects model. To construct such a model, I have multiple FLAGs, like the following:

```
y ~ x + z + FlagYear1 + FlagYear2 + FlagYear3 + FlagCountry1 + FlagCountry2
```

I want to perform another regression in which I have fixed effects for Year * Country, so that the model will be equal to this

```
y ~ x + z + FlagYear1Country1 + FlagYear1Country2 + FlagYear2Country1 + FlagYear2Country2 + FlagYear3Country1 + FlagYear3Country2
```

As I have 26 countries and 8 Years in my model, so it would be very time-consuming to manually construct all the FLAGs. I know there is a command to perform this automatically in Stata, how can I do the same in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by 'FLAG' you are referring to 0/1 coded indicator variables (or dummy variables) then R has an easy way to enter all of these interactions into a forumla.

If you have factor variables `country` with 26 levels and `year` with 8 levels then you can use

`y ~ x + z + country*year`

and this will expand the factors into every combination of country and year.

Look at the documentation for `formula` to understand how this works.

If you already have the indicator variables then you could use

`y ~ x + z + (FlagYear1 + FlagYear2 + FlagYear3) * (FlagCountry1 + FlagCountry2)`